# Неправильно работает Expander

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 2 `Expander'а`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="410" Margin="10,240,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="880">
            <Expander Header="Expander">
                <Grid >
                    <Label Content="Раздел:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,6,0,-29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Width="115" Height="23" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="RazdelNameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="121,6,0,-29" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="753" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                </Grid>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Header="Expander">
                <Grid>
                    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

                </Grid>
            </Expander>

        </StackPanel>
```

Почему при раскрытии они перекрывают друг друга, а не смещают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ох... Во-первых, забудьте что такое `Margin`, `Width`, `Height`. Существует `HorizontalAlignment` и `VerticalAlignment`, и аналогичное для `Content`.

`WPF` просто создан для "резинового" интерфейса и не надо пытаться вгонять без особой необходимости элементы управления в какие-то рамки непонятные.

В первом `Expander` я вижу у элементов управления `Gris.ColumnSpan`, но что-то не наблюдаю объявления колонок у самого `Grid`.

Посмотрите на такой пример:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Expander Header="Expander">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Раздел:" />
                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" 
                         x:Name="RazdelNameTB" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="Expander">
            <Button Content="Button" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Width="75" />
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
```

При том количестве строгих указаний размеров элементов управления что у Вас, я не сильно удивлён, что выглядит и работает не так, как хочется.